# How to update a program on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, update

I am using gammu-smsd 1.31 and the actual version is 1.37.
How can I update to newest version of gammu?
`sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` didn't help. It is still 1.31

More generally How to update a specific program on Rasberry Pi?

Comment: You'll have to build it from source if you want the latest version, or you may search Google and see if someone already has

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. In this case I would recommend to have the title reflect the actual question (along the line *How to update gammu-smsd on Raspbian*). Right now the title is extremely broad while the question is pretty specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like it's not on the raspbian repository as of yet.

If you really need it upgraded before they put it up there, here's the steps to compile it from source!

Update and upgrade existing raspbian packages:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake python-dev pkg-config libmysqlclient-dev libpq-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev libdbi0-dev libbluetooth-dev libgudev-1.0-dev libglib2.0-dev unixodbc-dev
```

Download and extract source code:

```
wget https://dl.cihar.com/gammu/releases/gammu-1.37.91.tar.bz2
tar -xvfj gammu-1.37.91.tar.bz2 -C gammu-1.37.91
```

Compile the source code on your raspberry pi:

```
cd gammu-1.37.91/
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

If all of this goes according to plan, you should be running version 1.37.91

BTW, this mainly comes from [the Gammu documentation](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/project/install.html#installing).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have downloaded the source code and If I try to configure it with ./configure, I get following error:  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:48 (add_coverage):
  Unknown CMake command "add_coverage". It is cmake related but I didn't find any useful solution in internet.

Comment: As per Simon B's answer if you do get this to work, you will need to run `sudo ldconfig` afterward.

Comment: Indeed, added to the answer 

Answer (score 3):

Pycvalade's directions [to build from source](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/project/install.html#installing) are correct, but you need to run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

After the install is complete.  This is very normal as it updates the [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) cache so it can find any shared libraries that were installed and presumably need by the application.